# Selecting max value on subset of data based on other column's value

Tags: sql

I'm looking to left join a value from a subset of data from another table, based on a specific value from the first table. Here are example tables:

```
table1
-----------------
key    date
1    2020-01-02
2    2020-03-02
```

```
table2
-----------------
key    date    value
1    2019-12-13    a
1    2019-12-29    b
1    2020-01-14    c
1    2020-02-02    d
2    2019-11-01    e
2    2019-12-02    f
2    2020-04-29    g
```

Based on the value of `date` for a specific key value from `table1`, I want to select the most recent (`MAX(date)`) from `table2`, where `temp` contains all rows for that key value where `date` is on or before the `date` from `table1`.

So, the resulting table would look like this:

```
key    date    value
1    2020-01-02    b
2    2020-03-02    f
```

I'm thinking I could use some type of logic that would create temp tables for each `key` value where `temp.date <= table1.date`, then select `MAX(temp.date)` from the temp table and left join the `value`. For example, the temp table for `key = 1` would be:

```
date    value
1    2019-12-13    a
1    2019-12-29    b
```

Then it would left join the value b for `key = 1`, since MAX(`date`) = 2019-12-29. I'm not sure if this is the right logic to go about my problem; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What DBMS do your use? [Edit] the question and add the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.value
        from table2 t2
        where t2.key = t1.key and t2.date <= t1.date
        order by t2.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as value
from table1 t1;
```

Note that not all databases support the standard `fetch first` clause.  You may need to use `limit` or `select top (1)` or something else depending on your database.

Comment: Thank you!! This is definitely the type of solution I was looking for but I couldn't figure out what the syntax would look like